# My code says the distance between these images is zero but they are very different

Tags: python, image, numpy, distance

I'm trying to see how similar 2 images are.
I have 100 images stored in the variable called "images". The shape of this variable is (100, 64, 128, 1).

I want to compare image 1 of this array to every other image (all other 99 images). And see how similar it is to each of those.

I tried using this code to calculate the distance between image 1 and 2, just to test it out because I know that image 1 and 2 look very different, so I should a distance far from 0:

```
i1=images[1]
i2=images[2]
def calculateDistance(i1, i2):
    return np.sum((i1-i2)**2)
calculateDistance(i1,i2)
```

But, I get 0 (which I know it shouldn't be). Any idea why?

Comment: I have checked `calculateDistance` it's working fine in the Images that I have loaded. Maybe you need to check your images, possible that all images are same.

Comment: Okay, I just fixed it and I get a value of "3233.892" Seems like a large value- is this normal?

Comment: Hi, Yes I just fixed something in there. Do you know what the outpuf values mean? I know 0 means they are exactly similar- but what does a value like 4000 mean? Is there anyway to turn this into a percentage to see the % difference of how different they are?

Comment: if you are looking for any image similarity algorithm to find % difference you can check [here](https://github.com/datenhahn/imgcompare)

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

images = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(100, 64, 128, 1))

i1 = images[1]
i2 = images[2]


def calculateDistance(i1, i2):
    return np.sum((i1 - i2) ** 2)


print(calculateDistance(i1, i2))
```